# Using $regex and $nor operator on the same array element

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have mongodb collection that contains groups of users:

```
[
  {
    groupName: "Blablabla",
    members: [
      { nick: "rick" },
      { nick: "ethan" },
      { nick: "jack" }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: "Lalala",
    members: [
      { nick: "rick" },
      { nick: "john" },
      { nick: "mark" }
    ]
  }
  ...
]
```

And I want the user (for example **rick**) to be able to search for these groups by the group name or by the group members nicks.

Here is my aggregation query (I am using mongoose):

```
Group.aggregate([
  { $match: {
    $or: [
      { 'members.nick': { $regex: req.query.searchquery } },
      { groupName: { $regex: req.query.searchquery } }
    ]
  } }
]);
```

And it works fine but when I pass something that matches rick as a searchquery it gives me just all groups that rick is the member of. Which is useless.

I tried something like this:

```
//req.session.user.nick equals rick

Group.aggregate([
  { $match: {
    $or: [
      { $and: [
        { 'members.nick': { $regex: req.query.searchquery } },
        { $nor: [{ 'members.nick': req.session.user.nick }] }
      ] },
      { groupName: { $regex: req.query.searchquery } }
    ]
  } }
]);
```

But it seems not to refer to the same member nick and all query returns empty array.

So the question is how I can select group where array element value matches regular expression and at the same time doesn't equal rick?

### **Example:**

Using this aggregation:

```
Group.aggregate([
  { $match: {
    $or: [
      { 'members.nick': { $regex: req.query.searchquery } },
      { groupName: { $regex: req.query.searchquery } }
    ]
  } }
]);
```

When I pass "blabla" as the search query it gives me the first "Bla**blabla**" group. When I pass "joh" it gives me "Lalala" group because user **joh**n is a member of this group.

But when I pass "ck" logged in as user rick i don't want it to return both groups (because ri**ck** is their member) but only the first group because ja**ck** is its member.

Comment: I don't understand what the exact problem is. Could you please post a sample of the expected result?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but I guess you mean that you want to exclude the groups that contain the session user's nickname from the results?

Comment: Yes, but only when there is no other user in this group that matches the search.